# Default device orientation in Xcode 6

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, xcode6, device-orientation

I've set up a new single view project in Xcode 6 for universal devices. This app is to run only in landscape mode on iPhones (even 6 and 6+) and any orientation on iPads.
In Xcode 5, you could specify in Deployment Info what device orientation can be used for iPhones and iPads. But in Xcode 6, it seems to have only one choice for all devices. This must be for the adaptive simplification process, I guess...

But, anyway, how can I specify these available orientations?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check the below screen shot you have option in xcode6.

[image]

Comment: Change the combo box "Devices" to iPad and then select all the orientations